# Bash: Command not found even though it's added to PATH

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I want to install dotnet to root on a linux vm and be able to run the dotnet with just a

```
sudo dotnet
```

call instead of needing to give the full path every time.

I installed dotnet on a linux VM with sudo using dotnet-install.sh. Dotnet is installed in /root/.dotnet/  . I can run the dotnet executable with sudo /root/.dotnet/dotnet --version which prints the version as expected. However, even though I did export PATH='$PATH:/root/.dotnet" to add the dotnet folder to $PATH, and I can see that it's been added by doing echo $PATH, trying to execute sudo dotnet --version will result in a Command not found error. How can I add the path properly so the dotnet executable can be ran with just sudo dotnet ...?

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try two options:

- Move the `/root/.dotnet/dotnet` binary to `/usr/local/bin`, and then you should be able to execute it.

```
mv /root/.dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin
```

OR

- Create a symlink so that you can call the .dotnet/dotnet from your bin folder of your Linux VM:

```
ln -s /root/.dotnet/dotnet /usr/local/bin
```

Comment: Thanks! The symlink solution worked beautifully!

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` doesn't typically use your personal `PATH` variable as that would be a security risk. A bad user could run a program with elevated privileges by installing it in a directory they control and putting that directory on their path ahead of a trusted directory.

To demonstrate, the output of these two commands will likely be different for you:

```
/bin/bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'
sudo /bin/bash -c 'echo "$PATH"'
```

The intended way to configure this is with the `secure_path` option in your sudoers file. See the [sudoers manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sudoers):

```
secure_path
Path used for every command run from sudo. If you don't trust the people
running sudo to have a sane PATH environment variable you may want to use
this. Another use is if you want to have the ''root path'' be separate
from the ''user path''. Users in the group specified by the exempt_group
option are not affected by secure_path. This option is not set by default.
```

If you trust `/root/.dotnet` and want programs there to be executable with `sudo` then you can add it to the sudoers file:

```
Defaults  secure_path="<current value>:/root/.dotnet"
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Sounds like it's a bad idea to install dotnet with sudo then, since it defaults to installing to /root/.dotnet. What's the best practice way of installing it?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your directory in below command. (Due to permission issue, command can't find from PATH). I had same issue after using this command its fixed.

```
sudo chmod -R 775 /root/.dotnet/
```